# How to move marker on google map V2 Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
        double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

        final LatLng maposition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);      
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(maposition));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("MONKEY.D").snippet("Hace la fiesta").position(maposition).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory));}}
```

How can I move this marker "maposition" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
map.addMarker(...)
```

returns a reference to Marker object. And that objects has a

```
setPosition(LatLng latlng)
```

method. So use it to move this marker wherever you want.

Comment: So i do Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("MONKEY.D").snippet("Hace la fiesta").position(maposition)));

And I add setPosition(LatLng marker); ?

Comment: but for lat and lng I should create a Ontouch listener ?

Comment: Well, it depends where do you want to move the marker. LatLng values can be hardcoded as well. Take a look on an official doc:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker?hl=pl There is even a "draggable" property that lets you move marker without doing anything in code.

Answer (score -1):

```
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("title")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker))
            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
```